# javascript Aertify not working properly with confrim box

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, alertify

i m using java script Alertify library to use fancy alerts. but i am facing problem when i want to use confirm box on client side if its true then it should run the server side event .but just on clicking button it runs server side code ..here is that code :please help me if i select ok then i should run server client..

```
  <asp:ImageButton id="remove" runat="server"
                                       ToolTip="Delete" 
                                       CssClass="controlbuttonjob"
                                           onClientClick="return  alertify.confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete?')"
                                           OnClick="remove_click"
                                           ImageAlign="left"
                                           ImageUrl="~/Style/delete.png"


                                              RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>'
                                          />
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of dialogs are runs and return right away.

Later if you press some of their buttons like the **cancel** or the **ok** they call the function that you have set.

The confirm is not even return true or false, is return the [object of the dialog.](https://github.com/fabien-d/alertify.js/blob/master/src/dialog.js)

```
// from the http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/
// confirm dialog
alertify.confirm("Message", function (e) {
    if (e) {
        // user clicked "ok"
    } else {
        // user clicked "cancel"
    }
});
```

So this is not working like the `confirm()` that waits for the user input.

Answer (score 0):

```
alertify.confirm("Message", function () {
    //clicked OK
    return true;
}, function(){
    //clicked Cancel
    return false;
});
```